# Awk regex expression to select for a certain number of delimiters in a field

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to select for a field which has exactly a certain number of commas. For example, I can select for 1 comma in a field as follows:

```
$ echo jkl,abc | awk '$1 ~ /[a-z],[a-z]/{print $0}'
jkl,abc
```

The expected output, "jkl,abc", is seen.

However, when I try for 2 commas it doesn't work.

```
$ echo jkl,abc,xyz | awk '$1 ~ /[a-z],[a-z],[a-z]/{print $0}'
(no output)
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It should be like:

```
echo jkl,abc,xyz | awk '/[a-z]+,[a-z]+,[a-z]+/{print $0}'
```

***OR***

```
echo jkl,abc,xyz | awk '/[a-z]+,[a-z]+,[a-z]+/'
```

***OP's code why its not working:***

Because OP is mentioning only 1 occurrence of `[a-z]` and `,` but that is not that case there are more than 1 characters present in line before comma hence its not matching it. With your given code `$1` is not required since you are matching whole line so I have removed `$1` part from solution.

In case you have multiple fields(separated by spaces) and you want to check condition on 1st part then you could go with:

```
echo "jkl,abc,xyz blabla" | awk '$1 ~ /[a-z]+,[a-z]+,[a-z]+/'
```

Answer (score 2):

`/[a-z],[a-z],[a-z]/` doesn't match `jkl,abc,xyz` because you didn't use quantifiers. Right regex would have been: `/^[a-z]+,[a-z]+,[a-z]+$/` e.g.

```
awk '/^[a-z]+,[a-z]+,[a-z]+$/' <<< 'jkl,abc,xyz'
```

However, to validate number of commas, it would be better to compare number of fields while using `FS = ","` like this:

```
awk -F, 'NF == 2' <<< 'jkl,abc'
awk -F, 'NF == 3' <<< 'jkl,abc,xyz'
```

```
jkl,abc
jkl,abc,xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

Your middle segment of the regexp wasn't accounting for more than one letter between the commas so you should have made just that one part of it `[a-z]*` or `[a-z]+` depending on your requirements for handling the case of zero letters.

Some approaches to consider to find 2 or more commas in a field:

```
$ echo jkl,abc,xyz | awk '$1 ~ /[a-z],[a-z]*,[a-z]/'
jkl,abc,xyz

$ echo jkl,abc,xyz | awk '$1 ~ /([a-z]*,){2,}/'
jkl,abc,xyz

$ echo jkl,abc,xyz | awk '$1 ~ /[^,],[^,]*,[^,]/'
jkl,abc,xyz

$ echo jkl,abc,xyz | awk '$1 ~ /([^,]*,){2,}/'
jkl,abc,xyz

$ echo jkl,abc,xyz | awk 'gsub(/,/,"&",$1) > 1'
jkl,abc,xyz
```